# Using an after queue policy daemon with postfix

Tags: postfix, queue, policyd

I have this scenario:

Postfix is configured with cluebringer (Policyd v2.1) and emails that are exceeding the quota are deffered. What I need to do is somehow use cluebringer in after-queue so it would recount the quota considering those deffered emails. The problem is that once an email gets in queue at some point it will be sent or it will expire. But if that email is sent - and by that email I  mean all the deffered emails that are at some point processed by postfix - the policy quota is useless. Of course I  can just drop the exceeding quota but that'd mean loosing lots of emails.

Is there any way I can force recounting the mails that already got into the queue using a after-queue policy daemon?

Comment: @masegaloeh - thanks man for correcting My english. Now I finally found My Self esteem. I was so lost without you!!!